# No matching function call for calculateSum

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am working on a program that prints NxN arrays, and got it working. However, I also have to create a void function to find the summation of subarrays within the original.

First array:

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
```

Function array must ouput:

```
8 12
20 24
```

My problem right now is an error, "No matching function call for calculateSum." Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks for the time on reading this post.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>

void calculateSum(int **arrays, int size ) ;

using namespace std ;

int main() {

    int *number, i, j, *n, counter = 0 ;


    cout << "Enter a value for a  n*n array: " ;
    cin >> *number ;

    *n = *number ;

    int array[*number][*number] ;

    cout << "This is the first array:  " << endl ;
    for (i = 0 ; i <= (*n - 1)  ; i ++) {
        for(j = 0 ; j <=  (*n - 1) && counter < ((*n)*(*n)); j ++, counter ++){
             array[i][j] = counter ;
             cout << setw(6)<< array[i][j]  ;
        }
    cout << endl ;
}

calculateSum(array, *number ) ;

return 0 ;
}

void calculateSum(int **arrays, int *size ) {

int **newLand ;
for(int i = 0; i < *size ; i++) {
    newLand[i] = new int[*size];
for(int j = 0; j < *size ; j++) {
          newLand[i][j] = arrays[i][j] + arrays[i][j+1] + arrays[i+1][j] + arrays[i+1]     [j+1]; //equation to add the numbers
 }
 }
```

Comment: Your function declaration does not match the definition.  See your second argument (int in declaration, int* in definition)

Comment: It's a good idea to indent your code consistently if you want other people to read it. A lot of people will take one look at this and not bother reading it because of the messy indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch of types between your declaration and definition. For your usage I'd recommend an `int` in both places since it represents the size and is not being changed. That way you don't need to dereference the pointer repeatedly in the body of your function.

```
void calculateSum(int **arrays, int size);
...
calculateSum(&array, number);
...
void calculateSum(int **arrays, int size) {
```